# New Landingpage using PayPal ExpressCheckout

Tags: paypal

I am using ExpressCheckout in several shops. Since a couple of weeks there is a problem with the landingpage. Instead of a landingpage with guest payment options or even price-information a stupid login page is shown.

Please take look at the image I made.
[image: New and old Landingpage]

It worked before and with my sandbox I still get the old Landingpage. Because there are no price-information many customers cancel the checkout process now.

Comment: Jut so mention.... Solutiontype is Sole, Landingpage is Billing and I already tried to use version 112.0 with USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid the new version of the landing page, but if you have all of the parameters set in the request the way you say then you should see a button that says "Pay with Debit or Credit Card" instead of "Create an Account".

Here's a screenshot of what I get.  You'll notice the pricing has been moved into a drop-down.

[image: PayPal EC Landing Page]

Comment: Hello Andrew. Thank you for your response. But I still don't know why there is no shopping cart/pricing at the page. Also the button Pay with Debit or Credit Card is not available.